# Javascript matching strings to partial matches

Tags: javascript

How can I make a partial string match in Javascript?

e.g. to match 'Alf'

- 'Alfred' -> true
- 'Alf' -> true
- 'alf' -> true
- 'al' -> true
- 'altered' -> false
- 'half' -> false
- '' -> false
- 'bob' -> false

https://jsfiddle.net/zbzc5tqe/1/

I would welcome shorter / more use of javascript inbuilt functions.

```js
var arr = ['Alfred', 'Alf', 'alf', 'al', 'altered', 'half', '', 'bob'];

arr.forEach(function(element) {
  add(element + "->" + matches(element, 'Alf'));
});

function ignoreCase(s1, s2) {
  var needleRegExp = new RegExp('^' + s2 + "$", "i");
  return needleRegExp.test(s1)
}

function partializer(string) {
  var out = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < string.length; i++) {
    out.push(string.slice(0, i));
  }
  return out;
}

function matches(text, partial) {
  var parts = partializer(partial);
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if (startsWith(text, parts[i])) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function startsWith(text, element) {
  var s2 = text.split(0, element.length - 1);
  return ignoreCase(element, s2);
}

function add(text) {
  var olList = document.getElementById('list');
  var newListItem = document.createElement('li');
  newListItem.innerText = text;
  olList.appendChild(newListItem);
}
```

```html
<ol id="list">
</ol>
```

Comment: I recommend looking into Regular Expressions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like you just want to know if a string starts with the substring:

```js
function test(arr, sub) {
  sub = sub.toLowerCase();
  return arr.map(str => str
    .toLowerCase()
    .startsWith(sub.slice(0, Math.max(str.length - 1, 1)))
  );
}

var arr = ['Alfred', 'Alf', 'alf', 'al', 'altered', 'half', '', 'bob'];

var results = test(arr, 'alf');
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Ah yeah, I was looking at this backwards. didn't think of trimming the "input" thanks.

Comment: With the caveat that str.toLowerCase isn't internationalisation friendly.

Comment: I wasn't expecting startsWith to work this way with blank input either.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach, good catch on the internationalisation. Also, depending on your browser support, startsWith may not be supported, however, it's an easy swap to indexOf == 0.

Comment: sub.slice(0, sub.length - 1)) looks suspicious, but the test cases work... i would have expected sub.slice(0, str.length - 1)) ?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach, you're absolutely right, it should be `str.length`. It just happened to pass because of the length of the substring - 1 at the matched the str.length But other cases would definitely have broken.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach, I added two improvements. 1, the substring should be lowercase when checking. And 2, the sub.slice should always have a minimum of 1, otherwise just passing 'a' will produce the wrong result.

Answer (score 4):

Using .indexOf to find if there is any matches in the string.
Refer to

```
function matches(text, partial) {
  return text.toLowerCase().indexOf(partial.toLowerCase()) > -1;
}

function matchesCase(text, partial) {
  return text.indexOf(partial) > -1;
}

https://jsfiddle.net/zbzc5tqe/3/
```

Use the matchesCase() function if you would like to match case sensitive only.

Comment: `al` should be `true`, and `half` should be `false`.

Comment: Didn't really aware of the 'al' should be true and 'half' should be false.
Agree that your answer works better if replaced with the indexOf == 0 as 'A' would be false if using the startWith method

Comment: I've edited to add an extra test case: https://jsfiddle.net/zbzc5tqe/5/

Answer (score 2):

didnt check partial usecase before, you can use regex like the one below

```
   var value = 'ALF';
   var comparor = value.slice(0, element.length - 1);
   var regexp = new RegExp("^"+comparor, "i");
   regexp.test(element);
```

```js
var arr = ['Alfred', 'Alf', 'alf', 'al', 'half', '', 'bob'];
var value = '00';
arr.forEach(function(element) {
    var comparor = (element.length > 1 ) ? value.slice(0, element.length - 1) : value;
    var regexp = new RegExp("^"+comparor, "i");
  add(element + "->" + regexp.test(element));
});



function add(text) {
  var olList = document.getElementById('list');
  var newListItem = document.createElement('li');
  newListItem.innerText = text;
  olList.appendChild(newListItem);
}
```

```html
<ol id="list">
</ol>
```

Comment: Your answer fails the following test case: 'al' -> true

Comment: sorry for a 3 years later comment, but passing in a single character as the value, such as "o" fails, it returns the empty value (from your jsFiddle example) as true, when it should be false.

Comment: @Andrew good catch ,i didn't check the all the testcases :) have made the change in the code to include the use case u have mentioned . obviously doing slice on a single charector or empty charector and subracting it with 1 will result in a empty value rather then the expected value