# How to implement a filter that takes into account the user's typo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, edit-distance

I have the following pseudocode with the filter implementation, it works by coincidence with what the user entered in the input field.

When the user enters the word `"tes"`, he sees item `"test"`, if he writes `"tesz"`, then he will not see items.
How can you implement the functionality that the user will allow if he typed(
entered incorrectly)  in a 1 letter word, still get the desired result, because it often happens that the user misses and writes the wrong letter.

!That is, I need a filter that, if you make a typo, will still display a suitable result, how can I achieve such an effect? In this case, they are not interested in any complex calculation algorithms, but at least a typo in 1 character

my code example

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const mock = ["item1", "test", "item2", 'some data'];

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [items, setItems] = useState(mock);
  const [filteredItem, setFilteredItem] = useState(mock);

  const onChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setValue(value);
    const filteredItems = items.filter((el) => {
      return el.includes(value);
    });
    setFilteredItem(filteredItems);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={onChange} value={value} />
      <ul>
        {filteredItem.map((el) => {
          return <li>{el}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

link to codesandbox
[filter_react](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-dream-rie7x?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: if you're interested in catching small typos, [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) could be of relevance. There are react libraries to take that into use if you just search with that term.

Comment: is it not so easy to do it manually?

Comment: will sub string search works like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43750172/javascript-matching-strings-to-partial-matches)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this
use string similarity to match the best one, is you want to match the top three values to compare and get the top matches(this string-similarity npm's rating looks like always return 0 maybe need you to find another one).

https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-lalande-muf0q?file=/src/App.js

[image]